# Append/prepend an item in an HStack while retaining its original center

Tags: layout, swiftui, hstack

I currently have a simple VStack that is aligned center:

```
VStack {
  Image(systemName: "arrow.down")
    .foregroundColor(.red)
  Text("AAA")
}
```

[image]

(Notice how the red arrow is perfectly aligned to the center of the label.)

Now I'd like to add another item to the Text row (e.g. with an HStack), but still have "AAA" be in the center of the container:

```
VStack {
  Image(systemName: "arrow.down")
    .foregroundColor(.green)

  HStack {
    Image(systemName: "star")
    Text("AAA")
  }
}
```

Problem is it's no longer centered (as is evidenced by the fact that the arrow is not aligned):

[image]

---

### Attempt 1: Alignment guides

I tried to fix this by creating a custom alignment guide:

```
extension HorizontalAlignment {
  struct CustomAlignment: AlignmentID {
    static func defaultValue(in context: ViewDimensions) -> CGFloat {
      return context[HorizontalAlignment.center]
    }
  }

  static let custom = HorizontalAlignment(CustomAlignment.self)
}
```

```
VStack(alignment: .custom) {
  Image(systemName: "arrow.down")
    .foregroundColor(.blue)
    .alignmentGuide(.custom, computeValue: { d in d[HorizontalAlignment.center] })

  HStack {
    Image(systemName: "star")
    Text("AAA")
      .alignmentGuide(.custom, computeValue: { d in d[HorizontalAlignment.center] })
  }
}
```

Although the arrow was now aligned properly, it moved the arrow instead of keeping the arrow where it was and moving the HStack instead:

[image]

(Notice how in this image although the blue arrow is aligned with the "AAA", it's no longer in the center (i.e. aligned with the other arrows).)

---

### Attempt #2: Alignment guides + offset

I can temporarily fix this by hardcoding an offset:

```
VStack(alignment: .custom) {
    Image(systemName: "arrow.down")
      .foregroundColor(.yellow)
      .alignmentGuide(.custom, computeValue: { d in d[HorizontalAlignment.center] })

    HStack {
      Image(systemName: "star")
      Text("AAA")
        .alignmentGuide(.custom, computeValue: { d in d[HorizontalAlignment.center] })
    }
  }.offset(x: -15)
```

It now looks correct:

[image]

Problem is I needed to hardcode this -15 value, and using offsets is not ideal.

---

### Attempt #3: Hidden view

Another workaround is to just add a hidden view at the end which is the same size.

```
VStack {
  Image(systemName: "arrow.down")
    .foregroundColor(.purple)

  HStack {
    Image(systemName: "star")
    Text("AAA")
    Image(systemName: "star")
      .opacity(0)
  }
}
```

[image]

I'd rather avoid a solution that uses a hidden view. It also makes the HStack bigger than it actually needs to be.

---

Is there any other way to keep the "AAA" aligned to the center of the screen, but add the star to its left?

I'd like to avoid hardcoding any values since the label or image may change one day.

Comment: I think the alignmentguide solution is very good. SwitUI would always center the whole HStack ... but there is an option:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to solve this, and perhaps the simplest, is to use your custom alignment guide and make the arrow down image take up all available horizontal space.

You can do that by adding a `.frame(maxWidth: .infinity)`.

```
VStack(alignment: .custom) {
  Image(systemName: "arrow.down")
    .foregroundColor(.gray)
    .alignmentGuide(.custom, computeValue: { d in d[HorizontalAlignment.center] })
    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity) // Add frame here

  HStack {
    Image(systemName: "star")
    Text("AAA")
      .alignmentGuide(.custom, computeValue: { d in d[HorizontalAlignment.center] })
}
```

This gives the following output:

[image]

If you are needing to make the arrow down image resizeable make sure you set the frame for the size of the image before you set the frame with the maxWidth.

```
Image(systemName: "arrow.down")
  .resizable()
  .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
  .foregroundColor(.gray)
  .alignmentGuide(.custom, computeValue: { d in d[HorizontalAlignment.center] })
  .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
```

Comment: This is great. The image was just meant as a way to visualize where the center is. Is there a way to do this while removing the image too?

Comment: I was able to git it working by replacing the `Image` with `Color.clear.frame(height: 0)`, but I'd prefer a solution that didn't need an invisible view like this (if possible).

Comment: I think you will struggle to do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var offset: CGFloat = .zero
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Image(systemName: "arrow.down")
                .foregroundColor(.green)
            
            HStack(spacing: 0) {
                Image(systemName: "star")
                    .overlay(
                        GeometryReader { geo in
                            Color.clear.onAppear {
                                offset = geo.size.width
                            }
                        }
                    )

                Text("AAA")
            }
            .offset(x: -offset/2)
        }
    }
}
```